# What should be done with questions like this?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed a few question in ask ubuntu like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767526/install-opencv-3-1-0), where a comment is enough to solve the OP's question. Should questions this this be flagged(if so which flag should be used) or is it required to write a proper answer.

Comment: Downvoting is obviously an option.

Comment: As it was you who answered it in comments, why not make an answer? It helped one person and may help others in the future.

Comment: answer the question if you can, lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can totally understand the feeling that these questions are too trivial to spend an answer on, and you have the impression there is "no honor in answering". At the same time, it obviously was an issue to OP, so it should be answered.

*IF* there is no valid reason to close the question as  *unclear* or *a duplicate* or whatever, comment- answering is a pain; the question will  never get the status of "answered". No one will ever post the same comment as an answer most likely, and the question will have an eternal live in between: answered but not answered. Always popping up in the section "unanswered", unless it is heavily downvoted, but why would it? The question is valid.

Therefore, if you can, answer it, even if the answer is obvious to you, to OP it wasn't.